# What is preventing me from upgrading / installing Fixefox extensions?

Tags: mac, firefox, download

I am trying to install a Firefox extension into Firefox 3.6.13 under OS X 10.5.8, and I keep getting an error message:

[image: OMG WTF?]

> Firefox could not install the file at
>
> because: Download error -228

[I have read this](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Unable_to_install_themes_or_extensions_-_Firefox#Download_Error_-228) and found it unhelpful. My cache is 500 MB and `~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems` *is* writable:

```
[jnet@Stan ~]$ ls -la ~/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems
total 16
drwx------    5 jnet  jnet   170 Jan 27 20:51 .
```

Any idea how I can correct this?

Answer (score 2):

Try to rightclick and save the .xpi file. If you can do it, you can execute it or drag it to Firefox to install it.

Comment: OK, this did work, thanks. I couldn't even download the extension in Firefox but I could via `wget`. I'd still like to solve the actual problem though!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you've downloaded the .xpi file to your computer, try opening a Finder window at its location and the Firefox add-on manager window simultaneously, and then dragging the .xpi file to the add-on manager window.

Comment: Right I can download and install the xpi files, but that's not my question. What I want is to have them install automatically like they're supposed to. Or to make updates work. I.E. how do I stop the above error from appearing?